# searching an aspx database

Tags: asp.net, database

the database that i am scraping is located here: https://www2.cslb.ca.gov/OnlineServices/CheckLicenseII/CheckLicense.aspx

what i would like to do is:

1. use a wildcard search to find companies with "roof" or "roofing" in the name.

i can perform this search "roof%". however, "%roof" or "* roof%" doesn't work. i am more interested in figuring out how to make the later query work.

example:

xyz roofing co
cal roofers inc

can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no such thing as an aspx database.
2. There's no way for you to derive a substring search, as you are attempting to do, if the site doesn't support it.  The 'search tips' page tells you exactly what is valid:

   https://www2.cslb.ca.gov/OnlineServices/CheckLicenseII/CheckLicense.aspx

We have no 'magical' way of making the site do more than it was designed to do.